# docker cant find environment file that definitly exists

Tags: docker

For some reason I cant copy this `.env` file with docker compose.

I get an error:

failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref P7HG:437G:LTTO:46LJ:7DOL:LGFQ:P7GQ:YW5M:RZV2:E4OL:HEQW:3GNM::pgh0i83f6t5m5ko3ng9naj74n: "/.env": not found

Here is my project structure:

```bash
tree -a  
├── docker-compose.yml  
├── .env  
├── readme.md  
├── src  
│   ├── app.py  
│   ├── authenticate.py  
│   ├── dockerfile  
│   └── requirements.txt  
└── test.txt
```

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.11
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nano
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/

COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ../.env /usr/src/app/
COPY . /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Even if I put the absolute path, it still does not work:

```
FROM python:3.10.11
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nano
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/

COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY /media/frank/T721/dev/app/.env /usr/src/app/
COPY . /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

```
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref P7HG:437G:LTTO:46LJ:7DOL:LGFQ:P7GQ:YW5M:RZV2:E4OL:HEQW:3GNM::zvn3xxsp7fh929ia473mpmtvc: "/media/frank/T721/dev/app/.env": not found
```

But the file is definitly there:

```bash
cat /media/frank/T721/dev/app/.env
FLASK_PORT=5000
AUTH_DB_NAME=mydb
AUTH_DB_PORT=1234
AUTH_DB_HOST=10.0.0.28
AUTH_DB_PASSWORD=mypass
AUTH_DB_USER=root
```

Does it need an escape character or something? I believe I have done this in the past many times and it has worked without issue. I do not have a `dockerignore` file.

It only works if I move the .env file to the same directory, then it copies everything at once with the command `COPY . /usr/src/app/`. It doesn't work if I manually specify the `.env` file.

Comment: Is it possible the second line after copying over the `.env` : `COPY . /usr/src/app/` is overwriting the directory and essentially removing the `.env`?

Comment: So what is the content of docker compose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> COPY ../.env
> ```

It is not possible to access anything outside docker *context*. I will gues that the *context* is set to `src` from `docker-compose.yml`. So it is not possible to access any files outside `src`, as all files inside `src` are *copied* to docker *context*. In short, it is not possible to copy anything from upper directories.

Set the context to root and fix relative paths in your dockerfile. Research [docker build context](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the Docker build content needs to contain all of the files which you transfer to the image. So if the `.env` file is not in the build context then you will get those errors.

There are a couple of options.

**1. Dockerfile in src/**

You can leave your `Dockerfile` in the `src/` directory. You'd need to make a few tweaks to paths though.

```
FROM python:3.10.11

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nano

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/

COPY src/requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY .env /usr/src/app/
COPY src/* /usr/src/app/

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Then *from the root directory* of the project build your image as follows:

```bash
docker build -f src/Dockerfile .
```

The `.` at the end indicates that the current directory should be used as the build context.

If you really wanted to build from the `src/` directory then you could also do something like this:

```bash
docker build -f ../src/Dockerfile ..        #  Don't like this!
```

The `..` at the end boost the build context up one level in the directory hierarchy.

**2. Dockerfile in root**

The other option is to move the `Dockerfile` up to the root directory of your project. Personally this is the approach that I would take. This would not require any changes to its contents, but would mean that the build command is slightly simpler.

```bash
docker build .                              # ⭐ This seems the best option to me!
```

If you wanted to build from `src/` you'd need to do this:

```bash
docker build -f ../Dockerfile ..
```

Whichever approach you take, if you want to include files from the root directory (like `.env`) then everything below the root directory must be included in your Docker build context. If there are large files then this will impact your build time.